# ON DELETE CASCADE pseudo delete

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, delete

For data integrity `ON DELETE CASCADE` is necessary but it's really dangerous when a delete affects like a Chain Reaction!

I know one way to prevent this is to make a pseudo delete by putting a "Delete" flag on in all tables where the record is being deleted from. But that's a very old style and clumsy way. How can I optimize this or is there any way to do it from inside database (SQL Code) ?

Comment: There's that or triggers - inserting the old record into a shadowing table, either on the same or a different server. It's only dangerous if your schema  parent-child relationships are poorly designed and there are other dependencies, i.e. triggers setting off other ones ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should look into using tombstone tables.

Here is what I mean: Suppose you had this table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ... other columns ....
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    ... other indexes ...
);
```

Now, create a table with the IDs that are marked for deletion

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_deleted
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

So instead of doing

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE MOD(id,100) = 0;
```

You would add the ids to `mytable_deleted`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable_deleted
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE MOD(id,100) = 0;
```

From here, you simply have to add the mytable_delete to all queries

To see all rows

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

To see non-deleted rows

```
SELECT * FROM mytable A LEFT JOIN mytable_deleted B USING (id) WHERE B.id IS NULL;
```

To see deleted rows

```
SELECT * FROM mytable A LEFT JOIN mytable_deleted B USING (id) WHERE B.id IS NOT NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM mytable A INNER JOIN mytable_deleted B USING (id);
```

To perform the actual deletion

```
DELETE A.* FROM mytable A INNER JOIN mytable_deleted B USING (id);
TRUNCATE TABLE mytable_deleted;
```

## CAVEAT

This will means that lots of SELECT queries must incorporate the tombstone table.

I have discussed this before : [Tombstone Table vs Deleted Flag in database syncronization & soft-delete scenarios](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14402/tombstone-table-vs-deleted-flag-in-database-syncronization-soft-delete-scenari/14419#14419). You should read the [**accepted answer from Leigh Riffel**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14412/877) instead of mine for a more honest critique as to which method is better in your case.