# Keep ROW = NULL or DELETE it?

Tags: mysql, performance, delete, performance-tuning

in this scheme

```
id  uid     content
1   1       A
2   1       B
3   1       C
4   1       D
5   1       E
```

If the User decided that he doesn't need the rows with `id = 3, 4, 5` Is it better to make him set their `content` to `NULL` or just delete the row?

This process occur many time And he maybe use the `NULL` slots again. Do I still use `UPDATE` and set it to `NULL` in case he will change it in the future? Or just `DELETE` the entire row?

The question is like: is it better to

`DELETE` the Row? `INSERT`| -> `DELETE` -> `INSERT` .. `DELETE` -> `INSERT`

or

`UPDATE` the Row? `INSERT`| -> `UPDATE to NULL` -> `UPDATE to value` .. `UPDATE to NULL` -> `UPDATE to value`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the rows will be re-used frequently, it is likely better to set the values to `NULL`, or simply add a column `is_deleted` to indicate that the row has been soft-deleted.  Continuously deleting and inserting rows can lead to a heavily fragmented table, and can be a cause of performance degradation.  This is typically used for queues where there are a known number of slots (rows) in the queue, and those slots are allocated ahead of time.

If the rows will not be re-used, or will be re-used very infrequently, then it's better to deallocate the space used by those rows.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [MaxVernon's answer (hitting the nail on the head, +1 !!!)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/199227/877), you could also consider using tombstone tables to monitor which rows can be soft deleted. See me post from `Mar 05, 2012` [Tombstone Table vs Deleted Flag in database syncronization & soft-delete scenarios](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14402/tombstone-table-vs-deleted-flag-in-database-syncronization-soft-delete-scenari/14419#14419).

Please consider which way you can live with

- Outright using `DELETE` will make a row get deleted and make the space available. The `DELETE` command will have to travel through the InnoDB Plumbing (locks, rollback segments, etc).
- Using a delete flag would also be subject to InnoDB's management (less fragmentation)
- Tombstone approach and delete flags put the strain of row deletion on application logic and a small code framework dedicated to it, whereas InnoDB has that baked in the Storage Engine

In the end, `DELETE` is the simplest and worry-free (or at least the most predictable) approach.